# xcode , Is it OK to use the value of UIImageView.accessibilityIdentifier?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I use Xcode 9

I want to put an `EncryptString` in the `UIImageView`.

I have checked that the UIImageView has a `NSString` variable,

I noticed that there is a variable called `accessibilityIdentifier`.

Is it ok to put the desired data into this variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can as well use the `tag: Int` property of any `UIView` objects.

Apple's Documentation says:

> You can use the identifiers you define in UI Automation scripts
>   because the value of **accessibilityIdentifier** corresponds to the
>   return value of the name method of UIAElement.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification